# Destructuring and computed propery name working together, es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I call a function with this code,

```
gqlActions('customer', 'Add', this.props, values);
```

or

```
gqlActions('customer', 'Update', this.props, values);
```

this funcions is used for add and update actions. 
On the function I use computed property, for example in

```
const tableAction= `${table}${action}`;
[tableAction]: valuesOptimistic,
```

It's working ok, my problem is in destructuring before, to use that variable after:

```
update: (store, { data: { [tableAction] }}) => { 
    data.customers.push([tableAction]);
```

it's not valid syntax... , before i've used hardcode for 'Add' action  :

```
update: (store, { data: { customerAdd }}) => {
    data.customers.push(customerAdd);
},
```

or

```
update: (store, { data: { customerUpdate }}) => {
    data.customers.push(customerUpdate);
},
```

becase I send 'update' property to work for a library that sends me the value accord to [tableAction] that I've defined in:

```
optimisticResponse: {
   [tableAction]: valuesOptimistic,
}
```

I mean parameter in denormalization is variable (update or add). I hope be clear.

my full function:

```
export const gqlActions = (table, action, props, values) => {

    const valuesOptimistic = {
        ...Object.assign({}, values, __typename: table'}) 
    };

    const tableAction= `${table}${action}`;
        props.mutate(
            {
                variables: values,
                optimisticResponse: {
                    [tableAction]: valuesOptimistic,
                },
                update: (store, { data: { [tableAction] }}) => {
                    data.customers.push([tableAction]);
                },
            },
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give an example of in- and output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [destructuring using computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Computed_object_property_names_and_destructuring)

```
update: (store, { data: { [tableAction]:action }}) => {
            data.customers.push(action);
         }
```

Comment: i can't use tableAction in optimisticResponse, is  a complex apollo client system for cache variables and objects to send and get

Comment: `tableAction` is a string right? So you can pass it as the key.

Comment: you update:  [tableAction]: valuesOptimistic, i think your answer is right, i'm going to test it